# Input variables dependable on another variable

Tags: java

I am just starting programming in Java and I have came to a little problem..

I want a user to input a number which I simply do with a scanner

```
int s = sc.nextInt();
```

but what if I want to create an input variable after that which will ask the user to input as many numbers that the variable "s" has.

For example: s=3
and user needs to type 3 more variables

```
s1=?
s2=?
s3=?
```

Comment: Do you want just 3 numbers? In that case you should do `int s[] = new int[3]; for(int i=0; i<3; i++){s[i] = sc.nextInt();}`. It will collect your input integers into array s. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: no not just three numbers....all the numbers that the number s defines...if user chooses 5 as the values of s...he should type 5 numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an array or a more dynamic data structure. In your case, if you ask "how many values you want to enter" you can do this:

```
printf("How many values?%n");
int count = sc.nextInt();
int s[] = new int[count];
for (int n = 0; n < s.length; n++) {
    printf("enter s" + n + "%n");
    s[n] = sc.nextInt()
}
```

But this is pretty old fashioned to use arrays for that. A more dynamic solution looks like:

```
List<Integer> s = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (true) {
    printf("Enter Number or -1 to finish.%n");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    if (num < 0) break;
    s.add(Integer.valueOf(num));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 s = sc.nextInt();  // Gets your input
 // If you don't want to use ArrayList use following:

 int ss[] = new int[s];   // This uses arrays

 // If you want Lists, use the following:
 List<int> mylist = new ArrayList<int>(); // If you want a list of your integers (flexible)
 for (int i = 0; i<s; i++){
     int st = sc.nextInt();
     mylist.add(new Integer(st));  // if you are interested only in Lists
     //ss[i] = sc.nextInt();    // if you are interested only in arrays
 }
```

Does that suit you? You have the option to use either one (comment out accordingly :D)